# Can I refer to a WPF element by a string?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to be able to refer to a WPF element in C# via the text in a string. Something like this:

```
SelectElementFromString("TestButton").Opacity = 1;
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Your question and sample code are rather vague. What kind of element would be selected?

Comment: Why would that method return a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need to?  Somehow I doubt it.  How about:

XAML:

---

```
<SomeType Name="_SomeControl" .../>
```

Code:

---

```
_SomeControl.SomeMethod();
```

Using strings in that manner is almost always a bad idea and serves only to make your code fragile (I say *almost* because there are some valid reasons, they are just not common).  Also, why does your method return a string?

EDIT:  Based on your comment here I would suggest that you simply use a collection to iterate through your controls:

> I would use that, but it is a pain to go [blah0.Property = true; blah 1.Property = true...] Is there some solution for this that I am missing

Almost every beginner programmer wants to do this (including myself some number of years ago).  Create a bunch of controls named something like `label0`, `label1`, `label2`, etc.  and then access them in a loop like this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < numControls; ++i )
{
    Control c = GetControl( "label" + i );
}
```

This is bad for various reasons and (luckily) completely unnecessary.  Load all of your controls into a `List<T>` and iterate through them as needed.

```
private List<Whatever> _controls = new List<Whatever>();
private void InitControlList()
{
    _controls.Add( someControl );
    _controls.Add( someOtherControl );
    // and so on.  Now just iterate through the list 
    // when you need to update or access the controls.
}
```

---

As noted by H.B., my answer helps the OP, but may not help future people searching this forum who actually need a direct answer.  So, here is a repost of Jon's answer (thanks, would throw you some more rep if I could =D)

> You can search the child controls of a FrameworkElement with [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx). To set the name for a control, use the Name or x:Name property from XAML.

Note: If you use x:Name, the control will also be available as a field on the codebehind for your FrameworkElement, and you will be able to access it directly.

Comment: I would use that, but it is a pain to go [blah0.Property = true; blah 1.Property = true...]
Is there some solution for this that I am missing?

Comment: Then use a collection.  Place all of your controls in a collection and iterate through them.

Comment: Okay, but is this the only way to add the controls to the List, or is there a more automated way?

Comment: While i absoutely agree with your answer this does not answer the question at hand, maybe someone wants to access a control via string for a "valid" reason, then this won't help.

Comment: @H.B.: I'm more concerned with helping the OP find a reasonable solution than future-proofing this thread.  It's a fair point though and we could always change the title.

Comment: @awesomeguy369: I suppose that depends on your constraints.  If the controls are all of the same type and you want all of them in your collection then you could loop through the Children of their parent control and take each element where the type is correct (or just use `IEnumerable.OfType()`).  In practice however it is usually a one time cost; once you layout your UI and setup your list you probably won't need to change it much if ever at all.

Comment: Well, you could just include the actual answer, after all it has been named several times already.

Comment: @H.B.: fair enough.  I added Jon's answer to the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 5):

You can search the child controls of a `FrameworkElement` with [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx). To set the name for a control, use the `Name` or `x:Name` property from XAML.

Note: If you use `x:Name`, the control will also be available as a field on the codebehind for your `FrameworkElement`, and you will be able to access it directly.

Answer (score 2):

FrameworkElement.FindName will steer you in the right direction... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
   string indx ="textbox1";
var txt= layout.FindName(indx);
             TextBox sometxt= txt as TextBox;
             sometxt.Opacity = 1;
```

this could help