# How do I access a control from a built string(control name)?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, controls

Problem code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfPlayers - 1; i++)
{
    if (i == dealerPosition())
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // e.g. outputs "tbPosition1"
        sb.Append("tbPosition").Append(dealerPosition().ToString()); 

        // The following line of code does not work as sb is a string containing 
        // "thPosition1", not my controller tbPosition1. How do I fix this?
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { (sb.Text = dealerPosition().ToString(); });
        break;
    }
}
```

Using C#, WPF, Visual Studio.

Comment: So just to be clear: You are using `sb` to build the name of a Control (for instance `tbPostiion123`), and then you want to use this to set the text for that control - i.e. the equivalent of the more explicit: `tbPosition123.Text = "..."`?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to do this. See this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428058/can-i-refer-to-a-wpf-element-by-a-string

Comment: @Kjartan - that is perfectly correct! Do you know of any way? :)

Comment: @Complexity - I am trying this approach to avoid a large number of if/elseif statements.

Comment: This is how i interpet your code: If i is at position X and that is the dealer position (DP) you  want to set a text control tbPositionX.Text = DP. But DB equals X so you will always set the text control to the same number as the numer of the text control. eg tbPositoin1.Text = "1" or tbPosition2.Text = "2". Is that correct?

Comment: @AxdorphCoder Yes that's is a correct interpretation with correct output! :) My trouble is using a built string (of a control name) to access the control itself. I am new to C#. Sorry if this is elementary stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    sb.Append("tbPosition").Append(dealerPosition().ToString()); 

    // The following line of code does not work as sb is a string containing 
    // "thPosition1", not my controller tbPosition1. How do I fix this?
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { ((this.FindName(sb.ToString()) as TextBox).Text  = dealerPosition().ToString(); });
```

From Complexity's comment though, the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5428102/1685167) mentions that you can add all of your elements into the list and loop / foreach that when you want to work on it:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxesToEdit = new List<TextBox>(){tbposition1, tbposition2 /*so on*/};

foreach (TextBox textbox in textBoxesToEdit)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FindName()` [should help you with this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx), but note that you may have to [may have to register each control as you create it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1755545/336648) if you add them after the control is initially created.

Answer (score 0):

In line with your answer to my quetion I would store my tdPositionXYZ in an array or List and do this instead of all of your code:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    tbPositionArray[dealerPosition()].Text = dealerPosition().ToString();
});
```